# Automatically suggest name(s) from contact list with respect to letter entered in textfield

Tags: iphone, text, uitextfield, contact-list

I have a textfield where the user enters the name.Now when a letter is typed in the textfield,let's say "T",then how can I get suggestions of names from contact list in iphone with respect to that letter entered.

Also I need to display the appropriate number corresponding to the name entered.

I have gone through [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/QuickStart.html),

Can anyone please help me out with valuable suggestions or sample code snippet:

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**

I was able to view the contacts in log(console),as I wrote the code suggested by Mr.Anil Kothari in viewDidLoad method

As suggested by Mr.Anil Kothari,I have implemented the search bar code for textfield delegate methods as follows:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)atextField
{

    if(searching)
        return;
    searching = YES;    
}

- (void) searchTableView
{

    textField = [self.fields objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *searchText = textField.text;

    for (UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews)
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            textField = (UITextField *)subview;
            break;
        }
    }
    textField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = NO;

    NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //searchArray contains matched names of friends with the searching string

    for (NSString *sTemp in contactList)
    {

        txtToSearch =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[sTemp substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,[searchText length])]];

        textField = [self.fields objectAtIndex:0];

        txtToSearch = textField.text;

        NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
            [copyListOfItems addObject:sTemp];

    }
    [searchArray release];
    searchArray = nil;
}

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)atextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
[copyListOfItems removeAllObjects];

    if([string length] > 0) 
    {
        searching = YES;
        [self searchTableView];
    }
    else 
    {
        searching = NO;
    }
}
```

But still not working :(

Comment: Try out this tutorial, it demonstrates the use of an automated search/ suggestion text field [link](http://www.dalmob.org/2011/03/01/alternative-autocomplete-uitextfield/)

Comment: Yeah I have already made a try at it its not wotking

Comment: please suggest me a sample code

Comment: the link is with sample code and it's working well.

Comment: I mean in the tutorial,there he took an array and added some data to it and populated number of table view sections as array count and when a letter is typed a table view appears with suggestions,say if a letter(let's say a) contains 5.Then a table view appears with 5 sections as suggestions

Comment: But I already have a table view with one field containing a textfield.Then when I type a letter the suggestions are not appearing

Comment: you have to implement of search method in textShouldChange method

Comment: Yeah I have done it,please see the code snippet in EDIT part of my post

Comment: HTAutocompleteTextField might be perfect for you, if you're interested in showing the autocomplete text in the text field itself: https://github.com/hoteltonight/HTAutocompleteTextField See the accompanying example or README on how to use it... it's pretty straightforward and flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Code I have already done in some application this kind of stuff:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tblSearchList.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
    contactList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    copyListOfItems=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate( );
    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount( addressBook );

    for ( int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++ )
    {
        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );
        NSString *contactName =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(ref,kABPersonFirstNameProperty)]; 
        NSLog(@"% @ ",contactName);
        [contactList addObject:contactName];
        [contactName release];
    }
}
```

searchBar Delegate's

```
- (void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {
    if(searching)
        return;
    searching = YES;    
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    [copyListOfItems removeAllObjects];

    if([searchText length] > 0) {
        searching = YES;
        [self searchTableView];
    }
    else {
        searching = NO;
    }
    [self.tblSearchList reloadData];
}

- (void) searchTableView {

    NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;

    NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //searchArray contains matched names of friends with the searching string

    for (NSString *sTemp in contactList)
    {

        NSString *txtToSearch =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[sTemp substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,[searchText length])]];

        NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
            [copyListOfItems addObject:sTemp];

    }
    [searchArray release];
    searchArray = nil;
}

- (void) doneSearching_Clicked:(id)sender {
    searchBar.text = @"";
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    searching = NO;
    [self.tblSearchList reloadData];
}
```

tableView Delegate's

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (searching)
        return [copyListOfItems count];

}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if(searching)
        return @"Search Results";
    return @"";
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if(searching) 
        cell.textLabel.text = [copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

fell free to ask for any further queries..

Comment: Thanks for the answer,will implement and get back to you

Comment: One small doubt,I want to embed the search bar in textfield,what should I do

Comment: In that case textField should have the same delegates(working same as UISeachBar) just find and replace them.

Comment: I mean,there is no requirement like placing a search bar in header view and do all operations for search bar.Just suggest the related contacts when a letter is typed in textfield,just like google suggestions :)

Comment: ya the code will be like so only...if you found the delegates of UITextField which will work correspondingly same as SearchBar. Then code will work fine. Just find the corresponding delegates in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html

Comment: Getting error "searching" undeclared or with suggestion replace "searching with searchfs"

Comment: declare Searching as BOOL type in header file        BOOL searching;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6647/discussion-between-anil-kothari-and-eshwar-chaitanya)

Comment: Sorry anil,was in home town on the acct of sankranthi occasion,health was not good,now back to work,please suggest me a way,thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use UISearchBar, implement the delegate method:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

Take the letter\s from searchText and fetch the contacts using ABAddressBookRef then update the SearchDisplayController accordingly..

hope this helps a little

Comment: Sorry for late reply & Thanks for the answer,can you please elaborate the answer a bit with sample code regarding ABAddressBookRef etc... bcoz I was getting issues with that one too,thanks in advance :)